How to correctly type the return value of a function with dynamic keys?
I have a function test in TypeScript (v5.5.4) that takes a fieldsMap parameter and should return a specific type based on the keys and values of fieldsMap. However, I am having trouble defining the return type correctly. Here is the current implementation:
function test<
  K extends string,
  T extends { [key in K]: string[] } = { [key in K]: string[] },
>(
  fieldsMap: T // { INFO: ['A', 'B', 'C'], OTHER: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] }
): {
  [A in K]: { [E in T[A][number]]: string | number }[]
} {
  // TODO: Implement
  console.log(fieldsMap);
  return {} as any;
}

I want to call this method like this:
const result = test<'INFO' | 'OTHER'>({
  INFO: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  OTHER: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
});

Currently, the inferred type of result is:
type CurrentResult = {
  INFO: { [p: string]: string | number }[],
  OTHER: { [p: string]: string | number }[]
};

But I expect the type to be:
type ExpectedResult = {
  INFO: { [p in 'A' | 'B' | 'C']: string | number }[],
  OTHER: { [p in 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z']: string | number }[]
};

Additionally, the following line should not compile:
result.INFO.map((I) => I.WORKING); // This should not compile

How can I modify my function to return the correctly typed object?

is the syntax test<'INFO' | 'OTHER'> required? it would be much easier if K could be deduced from keyof T

Exactly @Caleth. I was inspired by @Remo H. Jansen's solution. (1) Remove K and infer it via keyof T (2) Pass fieldMap as const. Thanks for your help.

You can try the following:
const fieldMap = {
  INFO: ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const,
  OTHER: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] as const,
};

type FieldMap = typeof fieldMap;

function test<
  K extends keyof FieldMap
>(
  fieldsMap: FieldMap
): {
  [A in K]: { [E in FieldMap[A][number]]: string | number }[]
} {
  // TODO: Implement
  console.log(fieldsMap);
  return {} as any;
}

Inference looks correct for me with that:


I would also suggest applying const assertion (as const) to the whole fieldMap variable. This way it's more obvious and readable as opposed to applying this assertion to a separate keys. But that's more a personal taste, than a strict rule

I don't have strict control over fieldMap, which is of type { [key in string]: string[] }. So, I can't use keyof on "FieldMap".
However, your suggestion using as const for fieldMap and not defining K directly solved it.
Revised function:
function test<
  T extends { [key in string]: readonly string[] }
>(
  fieldsMap: T
): { [A in keyof T]: { [E in T[A][number]]: string | number }[] }

Usage:
const result = client.test({
  INFO: ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const,
  OTHER: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] as const,
});

Thanks for the solution!

If you don't specify the type of K, it becomes much easier (although you need to specify as const on fieldMap otherwise it infers string[] for the types of fieldMap.INFO and fieldMap.OTHER.
We can pull out the type manipulations into helpers
type FieldMap<T> = T extends { [key in string]: readonly string[] } ? T : never
type TestResult<T> = T extends { [key in string]: readonly string[] } ? { [A in keyof T]: { [E in T[A][number]]: string | number }[] } : never

function test<T>(
  fieldsMap: FieldMap<T>
): TestResult<T> {
  // TODO: Implement
  console.log(fieldsMap);
  return {} as any;
}

Playground Link
